# Changeable and default values for select items

Tags: jquery

It's very difficult to explain but let's have a dry.

I can set the value of `#breakhourdropdown` and `#breakminutedropdown` *(they are `<select>`-elements)* to `'00'` or `'30'` if the variable `worktimewithoutbreak` is greater or higher than `21600`.

They should be the **default values** for the two elements.

But if the user want's to select another value by clicking the `<select>`-elements, nothing changes.

There should be the option, that the user can change the **default values** of the two elements.

```
$("#breakhourdropdown,#breakminutedropdown").change(function() {    

        var worktimewithoutbreak = 25000;

        if (worktimewithoutbreak >= 21600) {
                            var breakhour = $('#breakhourdropdown').val('00');
                            var breakminutes = $('#breakminutedropdown').val('30');
            } 
        if (worktimewithoutbreak <= 21600) {
                            var breakhour = $('#breakhourdropdown').val('00');
                            var breakminutes = $('#breakminutedropdown').val('00'); 
        }

});
```

**EDIT: Demo of the problem:** http://jsfiddle.net/XrcfM/

Comment: Make a jsfiddle with code to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @Palpatim i added a demo code with the problem to the question. http://jsfiddle.net/XrcfM/

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the values of the two controls after the user changes them. Obviously this results in the user not really being able to make a change.

The code should execute just once, at the start, and not when the user makes changes, so just lose the `.change` handler. Simplifying a little, all you need then becomes

```
var worktimewithoutbreak = 25000;
$('#breakhourdropdown').val('00');
$('#breakminutedropdown').val(worktimewithoutbreak >= 21600 ? '30' : '00');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're "change" event listener is changing the SELECT values back to the page load defaults event time a user manually changes them.

Change your JavaScript to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

        var worktimewithoutbreak = 25000;

        if (worktimewithoutbreak >= 21600) {
                            var breakhour = $('#breakhourdropdown').val('00');
                            var breakminutes = $('#breakminutedropdown').val('30');
            } 
        if (worktimewithoutbreak <= 21600) {
                            var breakhour = $('#breakhourdropdown').val('00');
                            var breakminutes = $('#breakminutedropdown').val('00'); 
        }

});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XrcfM/2/)